# How to deny pushes to master branch that has not yet been approved?

Tags: version-control, phabricator

How do I deny pushes received on the master branch if the corresponding commit is not yet approved in Phabricator.

Answer (score 1):

The way Phabricator itself deals with this is by using a Herald rule called *Cowboy Commits*:

When a commit is pushed to the Phabricator, Libphutil, Arcanist or Diviner repositories and it does not have a Differential Revision, it triggers an audit in the project *Cowboy Commits*.

This still requires someone to be watching the *Cowboy Commits* project, but it at least highlights them so they can be addressed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using "arc land" to push to master branch, then the push will be approved ONLY if its appproved. If the push is being done without using "arc land", then it cannot be checked before pushing upstream.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pre-commit hook to check the status in Phabricator, or ensure the commit message complies with the Phabricator template - this would prevent accidental commits. I'm not sure of the exact details how this would work, but this could be one general approach.